# How to check other user Session alive in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow questions but I couldn't find the solution that fulfill my requirement; if any one known about reference that exactly match my requirement please comment otherwise answer it.

I am developing   Enterprise application using Spring Framework in team, I have successfully integrate the "JMS" using ActiveMQ in application.
In this application User A send message to User B if user B is online otherwise not!

My Question is that how to check that User B session is live or not before user A message send to User B

Thanks In advance

Yasir Shabbir

Comment: What kind of session do you mean: the HTTP (Servlet) Session?

Comment: To check is User B are online or not before put message in JMS Queue

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you make communication with user B.

1. use web sockets to make push notifications to verify the status and push messages to user B.
2. client can regularly poll the server to get data if arrives from any user (in this case user A). if user B is online then only yhe polling can happen so it would be like user B gets a message from user A when he's online.

Comment: I am using Stomp web protocol for server push instead long polling!

Comment: so if a stomp client is connected/subscribe to a server, doesnt, it signifies that the user is online.

Comment: but if thousand users are connected with server by web socket , then how can I distinguish ? which message is for whom users?

Comment: okay, so i didnt worked on web sockets, but i think http based cookie can be accessed in web sockets as well . right ? in that case just map that cookie to their respective session in server.

Comment: Sir you going to another direction, I need answer of above question.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that monitor the users http session.

The simple approach is to have a Map or Set. Put the usersId (or what ever you use to identify them) in that Map/Set when ever they login, also put hat Id in the Session. Then use a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to get notified when ever a session get destroyed (that is the closest thing to SessionTimeOut you will get). When the Session gets destroyed the remove the userId from the Map/Set.

*(BTW. there is a new Spring Project: [Spring-Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/), I did not have a look on it up to now. Maybe it contains support for that problem.)*

Answer (score 0):

An easy way if you have a small number of clients is to use request-reply over messaging in conjunction with topics. Have all user sessions listen to topic (`pings` or similar). When a client wants to see who is online, they send a message (the contents of the body don't matter) and set the `JMSReplyTo` and `JMSCorrellationID` headers to identify a temporary queue that they are listening to for replies. The listening parties will pick up this message and all send back a message containing their ids. That way you have a living cache on the sender as to who is currently "online", the cache should expire every couple of seconds.

Take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html